# Ant in Netbeans: overriding run target doesn't work

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, target

I am trying to override the "run" target in a Netbeans project. What I'm doing is editing the file `build.xml`:

```
<project name="Test123" default="default" basedir=".">
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

    <target depends="init,compile" name="run">
        <echo>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</echo>
    </target>
    <target depends="init,compile-single" name="run-single">
        <echo>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

I tried to override both "run" and "run-single", but both things doesn't change anything. When pressing `F6`, the project's Main class is executed as before. The test message (`AAA...`) is not printed.

**EDIT:**
Created a [bug report](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=196133) for Netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions is, as mentioned in the answer to my [bug report](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=196133), to turn off compile-on-save.

Comment: "Compile on Save is a project-specific option. It can be enabled/disabled in project properties, on the Compilation tab." http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave#How_to_turn_it_on.2Foff

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be correct. Do not use F6, try to run the "run" target from the context menu on the build.xml file. That should work.

I think the default key binding for F6 is "Run Main Project" and that does not the same as "run".

Comment: Hmm, F6 is "run main project" only when there IS a main project. In my case when no main project is selected, it says "run Test123" (the current project). *What F6 does, is running the project using ant.* I think it is a bug (the fact that custom overrides are not considered), I will report it.