# NetBeans: Starting a .exe from the run (F6) button

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, target, netbeans-7

(New to NetBean using v7.1.1)

I am working on a java class library that is a plugin to a larger application (.exe).  I would like to have my host application start when press the F6 button or do the run->Run Project menu item.  I am starting from the java class library generated project and overriding the run and run-single targets in the generated build.xml.  I am testing the ant script with a run target like this

```
<target depends="init,compile" description="Test target" name="run">
    <echo>run target echo - Application startup would go here</echo>
</target>
```

Going to the files tab, right clicking on the build.xml file and going through the Run-Target->run context menu can the behavior I want (run target echo... in the output window or starting my host application).  But the F6 keypress just brings up a dialog titled Run Project asking me to Select the main class.  *My code will never have a class with a main function.*

After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147188/ant-in-netbeans-overriding-run-target-doesnt-work) and it's linked [bug report](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=196133) I have switched off "Compile on Save" which did not make any difference.

Am I using the correct kind of NetBeans generated project for my situation?

Is there some other netbeans setting that I need to [frob](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/F/frobnicate.html) the get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class with a main method in it to use for testing and remove the class when the library is working properly. I use Netbeans pretty much everyday and that's the simple approach I have taken to test the libraries I have created.